# How to find the nearest match for an integer in a given matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, type-conversion, distance, unsigned-integer

I have two matrices. Matrix `A(2048,64)` and matrix `B(10000,64)`. Values in each element of these matrices is a binary bit, so each row is a representation of a 64-bit binary value, so each row of the matrix has a magnitude between  `2^63` and `2^0`; Most Significant Bit to Least Significant Bit, respectively.

#### Problem:

For each row of `A` I want to find the value in `B` which is the closest to it in an absolute, numeric sense.

Consider `A(i,1:64)` being a binary representation of decimal value `Xi`, and `B(j,1:64)` a binary representation of decimal value `Yj`. So at the first step I want to find the best `j` such that `X1` or `A(1,1:64)` has the closest numeric value to the element at `Yj`, i.e. `abs(X1-Yj)` is minimized among all possible values for `j`.

The below image, brought from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195120-how-to-find-nearest-values-of-all-elements-of-a-matrix-to-another-matrix-in-matlab), describes my problem rather well, but the difference is that each of my values are contained in a row of a matrix containing 64 elements.

I tried to convert the 64-bit values to decimal, however `dec2bin` supports values up to 56-bit only.

[image: same scenario for rows with 1 column only]

Comment: You can't have a cell in a matrix. You can have a matrix in a cell though

Comment: Manually convert to decimals, then use the answer as given on Mathworks Central

Comment: @SardarUsama I now difference of cell array and matrices. May be I should use other words such as matrix rooms (instead of cells) but i don't know the right word to avoid misunderstanding. If you know please edit the question.

Comment: @Adriaan I wrote a manual conversion function however it does lead to loss of precision, i.e. for big values, lower bits of binary value are not preserved and distance is not calculated precisely.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide your 64-bit number into two 32-bit pieces, `b1` and `b2`, convert them to decimal values `d1` and `d2`, then combine them into a uint64 value that has enough precision to hold the result.

```
bin2uint64 = @(b) uint64(bin2dec(b(:,1:32)))*(2^32) + uint64(bin2dec(b(:,33:64)));
```

(This assumes that you have your data in the same format required by `bin2dec`, i.e. a vector of char. If you have a vector of numeric values, just add in a `b = char(b+'0');`)

Given an initial value

```
>> b = 1100110010111100101101111010100010101010010011010010000110011010
>> d = bin2uint64(b)
d = 14752868414398472602
>> r = dec2bin(d, 64)
r = 1100110010111100101101111010100010101010010011010010000110011010
>> any(b-r)
ans = 0
```

Since `b-r` gives all zeros, the values are identical. You can pass the entire `nx64` matrix as `b` and it will convert all of the values at once.

```
>> bin2uint64(char(randi([0 1], 20, 64) + '0'))
ans =

   4169100589409210726
   8883634060077187622
  15399652840620725530
  12845470998093501747
  14561257795005665153
   1133198980289431407
  13360302497937328511
    563773644115232568
   8825360015701340662
   2543400693478304607
  11786523850513558107
   8569436845019332309
   2720129551425231323
   5937260866696745014
   4974981393428261150
  16646060326132661642
   5943867124784820058
   2385960312431811974
  13146819635569970159
   6273342847731389380
```

You'll notice that I manually converted my random array to `char`. Assuming your input is numeric, you'll have to convert it first:

```
Achar = char(A + '0');
```

Yes, this is a pain, MATLAB should have included a destination type parameter in `bin2dec`, but they didn't. Now you can use your linked solution to find the matchings.

Answer (score 2):

### Converting your values:

Assuming your matrices `A` and `B` contain the *numeric* values `0` and `1`, you can easily convert the rows to [`uint64`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint64.html) data types without precision loss using the [`bitset`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitset.html) and [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) functions (and [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for a small efficiency boost):

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@(bit, V) bitset(uint64(0), bit, V), 64:-1:1, A), 2, 'native');
```

Compared to the [solution from beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46410368/52738), this one is over 4 times faster for a 10,000 row matrix:

```
% Sample data:
A = randi([0 1], 10000, 64);

% Test functions:
bin2uint64 = @(b) uint64(bin2dec(b(:,1:32)))*(2^32) + uint64(bin2dec(b(:,33:64)));
beaker_fcn = @(A) bin2uint64(char(A+'0'));
gnovice_fcn = @(A) sum(bsxfun(@(b, V) bitset(uint64(0), b, V), 64:-1:1, A), 2, 'native');

% Accuracy test:
isMatch = isequal(beaker_fcn(A), gnovice_fcn(A));  % Return "true"

% Timing:
timeit(@() beaker_fcn(A))

ans =
   0.022865378234183

timeit(@() gnovice_fcn(A))

ans =
   0.005434031911843
```

### Computing nearest matches:

You provide a [link to some solutions](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195120-how-to-find-nearest-values-of-all-elements-of-a-matrix-to-another-matrix-in-matlab) for finding the nearest matches for `A` in `B`. However, the fact that you are using *unsigned* integer types requires some modification. Specifically, order matters when subtracting values due to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). For example `uint64(8) - uint64(1)` gives you `7`, but `uint64(1) - uint64(8)` gives you `0`.

Here's the modified solution for unsigned integers, applied to the sample data you provide:

```
A = uint64([1 5 7 3 2 8]);
B = uint64([4 12 11 10 9 23 1 15]);
delta = bsxfun(@(a, b) max(a-b, b-a), A(:), reshape(B, 1, []));
[~, index] = min(delta, [], 2);
result = B(index)

result =
  1×6 uint64 row vector

   1   4   9   4   1   9   % As expected!
```